# PHP misinterpreting DATETIME input format sent via form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, datetime, post

I am using form to post date and time (selection made using datetime picker).Now Selection is working fime, But PHP is misinterpreting the format in which datetime was sent.

```
$_POST['From'] = "'".date('Y-d-m H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $_POST['From'])))."'";   

$_POST['To']= "'".date('Y-d-m H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $_POST['To'])))."'";
```

If i intended to send 14-JULY-2016...  I will send it as 14/7/2016, But PHP misinterprets it as 14th month.Hence Invalid time.

Whenever I cross 12th day, I always get `1970-01-01 01:00:00` which is the default when no datetime is provided. Plz Help. Thx in advance.

Comment: I sugget you have a read of the [PHP Docs on Date formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) explaining how it differentiates US and EU formats; then consider using `DateTime` objects and the `createFromFormat()` method

Comment: Thx for your suggestion. I will try the same.